# How can I match variable with cellObj value and verify the two are the same?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

```
jurisdiction == "Brazil"

if jurisdiction == "Brazil":
    for rowOfCellObjects in sheet['A2':'A5']:
        for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
            if cellObj.value == 'Germany':
                print(cellObj.value)
            else:
                print("No")
else:
    print("Try Again")
```

I know for sure that "Germany" is a string in those selected cells in the sheet. When you print the cellObj.value it returns "Germany". However, when I ask it to match, "if cellObj.value == "Germany"", it always returns no. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please remove the "jurisdiction" clause from your code, it only adds noise.

Comment: Maybe try explicitly casting `cellObj.value` to a string?

Answer (score 0):

If you think your code is correct but somehow the library or computer is trying to trick you then you should investigate further.

For example, adding debugging code to print or log the cell coordinate and its value would help you isolate problems such as trailing spaces or unicode / byte confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [iter_rows()](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.3/tutorial.html?highlight=iter_rows)?

I've never iterated over a sheet like you are trying to do, but I've done this instead:

```
if jurisdiction == "Brazil":
    for rowOfCellObjects in sheet.iter_rows('A2:A5'):
        for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
            if cellObj.value == 'Germany':
                print(cellObj.value)
            else:
                print("No")
else:
    print("Try Again")
```